# How to replace text with Regular Expressions in PhpStorm

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm, webstorm

There is a bunch of wrong examples on the net, which doesn't work.

In my 1000 files and 100 folders object-oriented WordPress/Php plugin project I needed to replace all language constants, like:

```
NRS_PHRASE1_TEXT
```

to dynamic language method calls, like:

```
$this->lang->getText('NRS_PHRASE1_TEXT')
```

The use of regular expression is a must here, to save days of work. But PhpStorm documentation does not gives you a tutorial how to do it, and Google and StackOverflow is a full of WRONG or 90% correct (not 100%) answers. So I made this tutorial to save time for you, so that you don't need to spend an hour experimenting while you get it right and working. Please see the answer in this topic, for my tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace a text in PhpStorm 8, PhpStorm 9 and newer, and probably in WebStorm 10 as well, open your project, right click on plugin folder, in which you want to replace code, select 'Replace in Path' option. The follow the tutorial bellow.

### To replace FROM => TO:

```
NRS_PHRASE1_TEXT => $this->lang->getText('NRS_PHRASE1_TEXT')
NRS_PHRASE_TWO_TEXT => $this->lang->getText('NRS_PHRASE_TWO_TEXT')
```

### Search select this search mode:

Regular expression

### In "SEARCH" field value enter this phrase:

```
NRS_([A-Z_0-9]+)_TEXT
```

### In "REPLACE" field value enter this phrase:

```
\\$this->lang->getText('NRS_$1_TEXT')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Search field, start typing regular expression that describes all title attributes. Note that though the regular expression \stitle=".*?"\s*[/>]* matches contents of the title attribute, it is recommended to capture the groups for referencing them in the Replace field:
\stitle="(.*)?"\s*(/>*)
Note that for the regular expressions replacement preview is shown at the tooltip.

[See here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html)